# polymorphic equality in c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, equality

If i compare a base type to a more derived type in c++ should the `operator==` only compare the base type part, or should it return false if it is passed in a more derived type ?

For example

```
BaseType myBase("a", "b");
DerivedType myDerived("a", "b", "c");

myDerived == myBase // This should return false, right ?
myBase == myDerived // Should this return false as well ? How can the BaseType operator know that it's parameter is derived ?
```

I feel like both statements should return false, but i'm not sure how to implement the `operator==` for the base type.

Comment: It's completely up to you how to implement the operators. However, the `BaseType` operator can't check anything from `DerivedType` as typically the base class doesn't know anything about possible derived classes. Unless, of course, you implement the operators as free-standing functions with the correct arguments to handle both types.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "implementing the operators as free-standing functions"  How will the base type type be able to check it's difference from it's derived type ?

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer if you need to check that the types are different, you are no longer using polymorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking about polymorphic equality, it would only make sense to make the comparison polymorphically, via the public interface of `BaseType`. For example:

```
struct BaseType
{
  virtual int foo() const { return 42; }
};

struct DerivedType : BaseType
{
  virtual int foo() const { return i_; }
  explicit DerivedType(int i) : i_(i) {}
 private:
  int i_;
};

bool operator==(const BaseType& lhs, const BaseType& rhs)
{
  return lhs.foo() == rhs.foo();
}

int main()
{
  BaseType b;
  DerivedType d(13);
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << (b == d) << std::endl;
}
```

There are different ways of implementing this, but the basic idea is that the equality operator uses the virtual public interface of the operands. But the public interface could hide a lot of the logic, for example via a  member function

```
bool equals(const BaseType& other) const
{
  // Call virtual methods to determine equality.
  // These can be public, private or protected.
}
```

the non-member operator then calls this:

```
bool operator==(const BaseType& lhs, const BaseType& rhs)
{
  return lhs.equals(rhs);
}
```

Comment: if foo() was hash_content(), with suitable large return type, it could actually be used for the purpose